# Handling JSON body in HappyX

Tags: nim-lang

How I can handle JSON body in HappyX web framework? I have this code

```
import happyx

serve "127.0.0.1", 5000:
  post "/messages.send":
    # here I want to handle JSON
```

I want to send JSON like this

```json
{
  "text": "Hello, world!",
  "from_id": 100
}
```

I'm trying to use path params, but it not what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle JSON you should declare [request model](https://hapticx.github.io/happyx/happyx/ssr/request_models.html) that will handle your JSON. Here is example:

```
# model named "Message"
model Message:
  text: string  # required field of type "string"
  from_id: int  # required field of type "int"

serve "127.0.0.1", 5000:
  post "/messages.send[msg:Message]":
    # Now you can work with msg as Message
    echo msg.text
    echo msg.from_id
    ...
```